# Accidentally moved directories under root

Tags: ssh, data-recovery, root, mv

I've accidentally run this command

```
sudo mv /* /applications/minced/
```

instead of

```
sudo mv ./* /applications/minced/
```

This is all that's left in the root directory

```
$ /
applications/ dev/          proc/         run/          sys/          tmp/
```

I still have an active ssh connection to the server. I've tried calling `mv`, `sudo` and `chmod`... directly from `/applications/minced/bin/` or `/applications/minced/usr/bin/`, but nothing works, though I can locate them there using path autocompletion.

```
$ /applications/minced/bin/ls
-bash: /applications/minced/bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

I've read [Revert moving root directory recursively](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332019/revert-moving-root-directory-recursivelly), but mounting the system under LiveCD is not an option for me since it's a VPS, not a physical machine. Any ideas?

**Update**

I figured out this is due to library linkage problems, so I did this

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/applications/minced/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ /applications/minced/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /applications/minced/bin/mv /applications/minced/* /
```

Obviously I ran into permission problems. Calling `sudo` with the linker throws this error

```
$ /applications/minced/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /applications/minced/usr/bin/sudo ...
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /applications/minced/usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

As suggested by Barafu Albino, I've tried calling `su` with busybox (`.../bin/busybox su -`), but it throws `su: must be suid to work properly`. I guess this happens because `su` can't locate `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. Seems like I've screwed up the system completely.

Comment: No, su and sudo are messes up because mv probably broke their permissions. You'll need to reset the suid permission on su and sudo to get them working.

Comment: @casey I believe there is no way to do it without being root in the first place, is there?

Comment: boot off a live dvd or rescue image and then fix your filesystem from there.

Comment: @casey I've mentioned this approach in my question. I can't do that since the machine is a VPS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your applications can not run because they want to find libraries and those are misplaced too. Try using `busybox` directly.

```
bin/busybox ls
```

should work as `ls` and so on.

Comment: I tried a similar approach by exporting linker path, i.e. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/applications/minced/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and calling the commands manually `/applications/minced/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /applications/minced/bin/mv /applications/minced/* /`. But I no longer can `sudo`.

Comment: So what about busybox? It has `su` in it, too.

Comment: `su: must be suid to work properly`

Comment: I've updated the post to show what's happening.

Comment: Yeah this option would've worked if I had root privileges left. Next time I'll login as root in case this stuff happens. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Lets do another approach. I assume you do not know real root password. 
Here is a list of libraries that sudo needs:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffea6be9000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fbbad17b000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fbbacf78000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbbacd74000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbbac9aa000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fbbac73d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbbad5c5000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbbac51f000)
```

Here is a list of files in sudo package (only relevant ones):

```
/lib
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/sudo.service
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/sudo
/usr/lib/sudo/system_group.so
/usr/lib/sudo/sudo_noexec.so
/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
/usr/lib/sudo/group_file.so
/usr/lib/sudo/sesh
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/sudoreplay
/usr/bin/sudo
```

Try moving libraries to the binary, into the same folder. May be it will work. `su` has less dependencies, but requires to know real root password.

Comment: `sudo` and `su` won't run because they lost `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. Thank you for your help, but seems like, I've screwed everything up too hard to deal with it.

Comment: @EliKorvigo: They didn't lose `/etc/`anything.  They lost the setuid bit when you moved them.  They need that because you can't give the user root if you don't have root to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I just run into this problem exactly like this post. I'm using an Ubuntu server which has a disabled root user and is using `sudo` to do the root commands. so I can't log in with root user by any chance, the only way for me in the instance is making the `sudo` works. unfortunately, hours passed, I failed, that's too bad.

And for users who can log in with the root, I suppose you guys forgot to mention another way which may be much easier: `busybox sulogin`