# Moved bin directory and other folders

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, mv, busybox

I have done the typical newbie error and have moved important bash folders by mistake using the command;

```
sudo mv /* ../../../../../programmingajax.com/
```

This has then gone and moved lots of important files and folders resulting in me not being able to use the command line properly.

However reading around the internet I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44699/undo-mv-command) which explains that I should use busybox to use commands such as `mv`.

So I ran this command to move all the folders back to there original location;

```
../../../../../programmingajax.com/bin/busybox mv ../../../../../programmingajax.com/* /
```

After doing that it now tells me that I cannot move (rename) these files as I do not have permission.

So I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680035/accidentally-moved-directories-under-root) that I can use `su`

So I ran the command to try and move the folders back this time using `su`;

```
../../../../../programmingajax.com/bin/busybox su ../../../../../programmingajax.com/bin/busybox mv ../../../../../programmingajax.com/* /
```

But I get the error `su: must be suid to work properly`

Is there a way I can rectify this?

Comment: what about a using live-CD to turn all back.

Comment: See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/moved-bin-and-other-folders-how-to-get-them-back). Since you do not have a root shell, using live CD will be the best option.

Comment: Sorry bit confused on how would I go about this? As I am running it on VMWare I tried to go into recovery mode using the "shift" key but nothing happens, it just logs back into the main desktop.

Comment: Does this work? `../../../../../programmingajax.com/bin/sudo ../../../../../programmingajax.com/bin/mv ../../../../../programmingajax.com/* /`

Comment: @EvanChen: Good approach but it's actually more complicated because `sudo` is linked dynamically and the dynamic loader is not where it's supposed to be (`/lib/ld-linux.so.*`) and neither are the dynamic libraries (`/lib`). So it'd actually have to be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="../../../../../programmingajax.com/lib/$(uname -m)-linux-gnu" ../../../../../programmingajax.com/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ../../../../../programmingajax.com/bin/sudo ../../../../../programmingajax.com/bin/mv ../../../../../programmingajax.com/* /`. Bottom line: just use a live system; it'll be much easier.